# SQL Server select column from table where column in subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, subquery

I have wrong result in my query because I don't get any results but the definitely are there.

QUERY

```
 select nr 
 from table1 
 inner join table2 on table2.nr = table1.nr
 where table1.nr in (select nr 
                     from table2 
                     where columnn like '%value%') 
   and nr in (select nr from table2 where columnn like '%other value%')
```

When I only use first subquery I get results, but with the second subquery in it I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OR instead of AND

```
select nr from table1 
 inner join table2 on table2.nr = table1.nr
 where table1.nr in (select nr from table2 where columnn like '%value%') or nr in 
(select nr from table2 where columnn like '%other value%')
```

And join is useless if it is exact same query that u use.

Elegant way is

```
select nr from table1 
 inner join table2 on table2.nr = table1.nr
 where CONTAINS(table2.column, '"*value*" OR "*other value*"')
```

Comment: i cant use or becase i need the nr to be in the first subquery and the second 1 and like that i get results from nr in one of the 2 subquery's

Comment: can you post a sample data and expected output?

Comment: Tanx for the query i just need to add full text indexed on table2 will let you know result

Comment: Can you maybe help me with enableing full text search on a table in sql server 2008 becase its greyd out and i can not get it enabled